# Is it possible to update a Symfony project through Git?

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I have a running project with Symfony 2 and I want to control versions using Git. It would be very nice if I can version the bundle I'm working on right now and include it as vendor.

In the end, I would have an empty Symfony project and everything is running in the vendors and all updates are done via Composer.

**Is this possible?**

I know the question is not very detailed but this is the best I can do. Should you have any question, please comment!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - creating own vendor bundle - project and git strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy)

Comment: Hello Acrobat , thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Composer writes the exact versions being used into the file `composer.lock`, and will restore the result recorded there whenever you run `composer install`.

So the usual workflow would be to create the repository for your application, add a `composer.json`, add your dependencies including their version requirements into that file, and run `composer update`.

Then commit both composer files `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, but ignore the created `vendor` directory. That way you should be able to restore this committed situation any time later by simply checking out this commit and again run `composer install`.

You can add the call to `composer install` as a post-checkout command in your git repository to automatically switch the committed dependencies.