# moving custom symfony bundle to vendor folder

Tags: symfony

I am currently reorganising my Symfony project in which there are various custom bundles. 
Can anyone advise as to when do you move a custom bundle from the src/ folder to the vendor/ folder (by loading it through composer).

Comment: If the bundle is already pretty much independent in terms of parameters, code structure, interactions with other bundles etc. then it's a good candidate for moving it to an external repo.

Comment: This is a pretty good tutorial : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy