# How to use Own Symfony vendor bundle in Symfony based application

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating  my own vendor bundle using symfony framework. I have Sucessfully created using [Symfony2 - creating own vendor bundle - project and git strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy)

Now I want to use my own vendor bundle in the symfony project.I have successfully installed this bundle in another project.But I dont know how to use this.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Why can't you use it?  Have you initialised it in app/AppKernel.php?  Are you unsure as to your bundle's namespace?

Comment: Maybe when you read the bundle documentation then you remember how to do it ;D

Comment: @malcolm I have create my own vendor bundle like other bundle  "knp paginator bundle".bu I dont know how will they intreact with my controller.

Comment: What you bundle do, have it any services? Call it the same way as paginator.