# Creating vendor bundle in symfony2 and deploying it via composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundle, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to create my first vendor bundle. I have found a lot of informations in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy) but i'm stuck.

- My github repository is available here :
  https://github.com/vtedesco/Peary
- I have registered it in composer :
  https://packagist.org/packages/vted/peary

In another project I have installed it via the command `composer require vted/peary`, files are correctly visible under my directory `vendors/vted/peary`.

But when it try to add it in AppKernel.php like this:

```
$bundles = array(
    ...
    new Vted\PearyBundle\VtedPearyBundle(),
    ...
);
```

I get the following error :

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 24:
Attempted to load class "VtedPearyBundle" from namespace "Vted\PearyBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Vted\PearyBundle\VtedPearyBundle"?
```

I think it's maybe a naming issue somewhere but I can't find it. The [VtedPearyBundle.php](https://github.com/vtedesco/Peary/blob/master/VtedPearyBundle.php) class look good for me.

Comment: Seems like your composer.json PSR-0 configuration is wrong, have you checked how other bundles does it?

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo thx, it was misconfiguration of PSR-0, I switched to PSR-4 as suggested by Jakub Zalas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current bundle structure is more suitable for the psr-4 autoloader:

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Vted\\PearyBundle\\" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`target-dir` with psr-0](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#target-dir). However, the psr-4 autoloader is preferred.