# how to easily debug a symfony bundle shared across project

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php, bundle

I'm about to share a little bundle between two symfony projects, and I'm wondering how to do in order to easily debug it while I'm coding.

This bundle will be added to the composer.json dependency list, and the two symfony projects will have to do a composer update each time this bundle change.
I want to be able to test this bundle without this awful step. So how could I prevent myself to such a burden?

I imagine that I could use a third project dedicated to the debugging of this bundle with simplified access to the updates, but how?

1. I could use git submodule to host my bundle inside another symfony project who can act as an always up to date environment, but I had really bad experiences with git submodule and prefer to avoid it.
2. Another solution could be to replace the submodule by a symlink but this is not a shareable environment across a team (each team member as to make the symlink)
3. my prefered solution is a simple bash script could "commit + launch the composer update to the test project" reducing the pain.
   Finally while the two real project should rely on private github repo in order to get the code the test project should rely on a [path](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) repo in order to bypass my bad internet connexion.

**edit** : I ended up using a git hook (post-commit) that trigger a composer update on both my depending projects. My depending project having a dependency declared with a private git repo. This is simple to create, but the drawback is that the composer update is triggered after each commit.

my solution is not totally satisfying, but I can't imagine a better one, did I miss something better/simpler?

Comment: did you hcek this workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy

Comment: I think this is indeed the way to go, thant you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @numediaweb kindly answered, this wokrflow seems to be the way to go : 
[Symfony2 - creating own vendor bundle - project and git strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy)