# Symfony 4 bundles working

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony4

How can I create library bundle on Symfony 4?

In Symfony 3 I use this command: `php bin/console generate:bundle` but in new version not working.
And is possible use bundles like Symfony 3, for example, i have blog bundle and telegram bot bundle if not possible how to simulate in Symfony 4?

Comment: https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-a-new-way-to-develop-applications

Comment: @StephanVierkant I can not find my answer here

Comment: No, because Symfony 4 doesn't work that way. Read https://medium.com/@fabpot/fabien-potencier-4574622d6a7e

Comment: The question is relevent, therefore the downvotes are not needed. There is no official documentation on creating Symfony 4 apps yet except the almost copy-paste from Symfony 2 / 3, which is not quite relevant on the other hand.

Comment: @forsberg thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the logic for creating bundle doesn't change since Symofony 2.x. But now bundles are just packages, use for reusable features.
If you want to develop your own bundle just follow this post [Symfony2 - creating own vendor bundle - project and git strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy)
Since Symfony Generate Bundle isn't supported anymore in 4.x you have to follow this other post: [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

The SensioGeneratorBundle has been superseded by the Symfony Maker Bundle – see https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-maker-bundle for more information.

Comment: please tell me example like command i cant find my answer here

Comment: @A.Seddighi If you can't understand the link then it might be best to stick with S3.4 for now.  As of this writing, Symfony 4 was just released yesterday and it will require some reading to understand.  I should also point out that more than likely you don't want to create a bundle anyways.

Comment: @Cerad So how do you keep your app uncoupled in Symfony 4 now? The SoC (Seperation of Concerns) was the prime Symfony 2 and 3 paradigm, and the framework was very helpful in keeping this rule true.

Comment: @forsberg A few years after Symfony 2 was first released, the creators published a so-called [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html) document in which the use of application specific bundles were discouraged.  There are times when I find it still makes sense to create application specific bundles.  Usually when the bundles are truly independent and need to some extra configuration.  But to get started, it's generally best to follow the recommend practices.

Comment: @Cerad Yes I know about the best practices. The "discourage" part applies to the bundles which cannot be used "as is" in other apps (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles ). However, I do create re-usable bundles. The question about decoupling remains unanswered.

Comment: @forsberg Perhaps you can explain a bit more about what uncoupling/decoupling means in this context.  Though I fear we may be getting just a bit off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Fabien Potencier said in the Symfony 4 best practices blog post "Bundle-less applications is just one of the best practices changes for Symfony 4".

You must not generate new bundles, you can use default "App" bundle for your whole project.

You can look at this url for blog post about subject
[Symfony 4: Monolith vs Micro](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-monolith-vs-micro.html)

Comment: I want to generate library bundle for share code or etc. Like doctrine or guzzleHttp

Comment: I'm so sorry about my too late answer, I hope that you have been fixed your problem before this comment.

I hope I understand correctly. 

If you want to create a bundle for all symfony 4 projects and you want to publish flex package manager, please read the best practices page below. 

[Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

just try to install GeneratorBundle: [more info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html)

```html
composer require sensio/generator-bundle
```

and after you can generate your Bundle like this : [more info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html)

```html
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

Answer (score -1):

Start by creating a `src/Acme/TestBundle/` directory and adding a new file called `AcmeTestBundle.php`:

```php
// src/Acme/TestBundle/AcmeTestBundle.php
namespace App\Acme\TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeTestBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

After add this line in config/bundles.php :

```php
App\Acme\TestBundle\AcmeTestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```